# Odd memory leak with pointer arrays when multithreading that do not occur while single threading

Tags: c++, arrays, multithreading, memory-leaks

After spending an entire day debugging, I've noticed that memory leaks always occur when the following function is called:

```
void merge(TContainer<T> List2)
{

    TContainer<T> temp(this->Size);

    for (int i = 0; i < this->Size; i++)
    {
        temp.Interface[i] = this->Interface[i];
    }

    this->Interface = new T[Size + List2.size()];
    Size = Size + List2.size();


    for(int i = 0; i < List2.size(); i++)
    {
        Interface[i] = List2[i];
    }

    for(int i = List2.size(); i < Size; i++)
    {
        Interface[i] = temp[i];
    };
    delete[] temp.Interface;
}
```

Within the code:

```
    TContainer_Short<unsigned short> Temp = TContainer_Short<unsigned short>(0);
    for(int i = (ToUpdate.size() - 1); i >= 0; i--)
    {
        UpdateInUse = true;
        ToUpdate[i].Ad.push_back(AdQueue[i].Indirect[0].Address);
        auto Entity = ToUpdate[i];
        UpdateInUse = false;
        float HighestScore = 0;
        int Index = 0;
        //Go through all the advertisements on their queue
        //Make sure our last index is always the next plot point in our story.

        for(int j = 0; j < ToUpdate[i].Ad.size(); j++)
        {
            AdvertisementBase Ad = *World::get()->getTemplateAd(Entity.Ad[j]);

            float temp = returnScore(Entity.Index, Ad);
            //If its higher than our current score, set i to this index
            if(temp > HighestScore)
                Index = j;
        }
        //Index is last pos when we're currently continuing our plot queue. We haven't changed our mind about what advertisement we want

        if(Index !=(Entity.Ad.size() - 1))
        {

            AdvertisementBase *Ad = World::get()->getTemplateAd(Entity.Ad[Index]);
            this->reduceAdChain(Entity.Index, Ad);

        }

        else
        {
            //Makes sure that the entity is on track for the next goal that it had already determined
           plan(Entity.Index,AdQueue.Interface[Entity.Index].Indirect[0].Address);
        }
        Temp.push_back(Entity.Index);
        ToUpdate.pop_back();

    }
    if(!ExecutingInUse)
    {
        ExecutingInUse = true;
        Executing.merge(Temp);
        ExecutingInUse = false;
    }
    delete[] Temp.Interface;
}
```

However, I can't seem to figure out why it only occurs when there are multiple threads. The array itself is only ever being referenced by one thread at a time, (Atomic), so it *shouldn't* be a problem.

Deleting the Executing::merge reference makes the memory leak go away, and definitely speeds up performance noticeably in single threaded scenarios.

The thing that’s even more odd is that merge is used in other places:

```
void reduceAdChain(unsigned short Index, TContainer<AdvertisementReference> Ads)
{
    AdQueue[Index].Indirect.merge(Ads);
}
```

And no memory leak gets created, even though reduceAdChain is called almost a full magnitude more often than Executing::merge. And removing merge in this area, creates no noticeable performance increase, even though

A) The arrays being taken in by reduceAdChain for the merge are almost 3x the size on average than the arrays that pass into Executing::merge

and

B) The overall length of reduceAdChain is almost 5x the length of Executing.

However, executing does get cleared at the end of every iteration.

This is one of the weirdest things I've ever ran into in multithreaded environments.

Where Executing gets used:

```
        if(!m_simulated_entities[i]->ExecutingInUse)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < m_simulated_entities[i]->Executing.size(); )
            {
                // Retrieve Tag Data and Update Constants
                m_simulated_entities[i]->ExecutingInUse = true;
                ExecutingIndex = m_simulated_entities[i]->Executing[j];
                m_simulated_entities[i]->ExecutingInUse = false;


                TagIndex = m_simulated_entities[i]->TagIndicesPerEntity[ExecutingIndex];
                now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
                time_now = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(now.time_since_epoch()).count();

                if (m_simulated_entities[i]->Timing[m_simulated_entities[i]->Executing[j]].TimeConstant == 0)
                {
                    //Make sure all of our new attribute values still allow this entity to live
                    if(!m_simulated_entities[i]->updateTick(ExecutingIndex))
                        m_simulated_entities[i]->removeInstance(ExecutingIndex);
                    else
                    {
                        //Compute our new transfer constant
                        m_simulated_entities[i]->prepare(ExecutingIndex);
                        //Update the tagging system
                        m_simulated_entities[i]->updateTags(ExecutingIndex);
                        //Search for new decisions
                        m_simulated_entities[i]->ToSearch.push_back(ExecutingIndex);
                    }
                    //Remove the index from execution
                    m_simulated_entities[i]->ExecutingInUse = true;
                    m_simulated_entities[i]->Executing.Remove(j);
                    m_simulated_entities[i]->ExecutingInUse = false;
                }

                else if (time_now - m_simulated_entities[i]->Timing[ExecutingIndex].LastUpdateTime > updateConstants[TagIndex])
                {
                    m_simulated_entities[i]->Timing[ExecutingIndex].TimeConstant--;
                    m_simulated_entities[i]->Timing[ExecutingIndex].LastUpdateTime = time_now;
                    j++;
                }
            }
        }
```

For the test, updateTick is disabled and will always return true, since allowing that function to properly execute would have made finding the memory leak a lot harder.

Comment: What is Executing instance? How it's declared?

Comment: Executing is a list of all entities that are currently executing a decision they made via a fuzzy logic controller. I'll edit the post to show its use case.

Comment: Looking at your merge(), you allocate memory for the new Interface thats assigned to this->Interface. What happens to the old memory? That probably needs to be freed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in the function merge:

```
 this->Interface = new T[Size + List2.size()];
```

You should check if the pointer  `this->Interface` is `NULL` or not, if it is not, it should be freed first. Otherwise if the function merge is called multiple times, it will leak.

So the code will be:

```
if (this->Interface != NULL)
   delete[]  this->Interface;
this->Interface = new T[Size + List2.size()];
```

Comment: Yay! This seems to take care of the memory leak. Thanks!

Comment: Can't yet. have to wait 3 minutes

Comment: Whats weird is that there was no memory leak when only using a single thread. This works perfectly though

Comment: @LouisCastricato add a log in the function merge, and log the value of the this->Interface before allocating new memory,you'll find it out.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for possibly stupid question: if you have vectors as "ToUpdate[i].Ad" etc, why don't you use "this->Interface" as vector too? This could save you a lot of time hunting this leak.

Comment: Just because its easier to read, and using this->Interface everywhere makes it a lot harder to understand when you're moving everything to a cache concision architecture